# How can I backup an Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, backup, azure-cosmosdb, database-backups

I have an Azure Cosmos DB and I need to delete all the resources from this subscription. Is there any way to take a backup offline from the portal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE** : Cosmos DB now supports backup [Online backup and on-demand data restore in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#modify-the-backup-interval-and-retention-period)

---

You can use Data Migration Tool suggested on **[Automatic online backup and restore with Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore)** article to do the same.

There is no way to take a backup and import to Azure CosmosDB.

The recommendation is to **open a support ticket** (e.g. via Azure Portal) or **call Azure Support** to streamline the backup/restore strategy and to request Azure to restore the latest backup in case of a disaster event. In addition, you can contact the Azure CosmosDB team by sending an email to AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com.

Comment: The referred page does not have any useful information, typical Microsoft style page

Answer (score 2):

Sajeetharan's answer is wrong.

```
mongodump --uri="PRIMARY_CONNECTION_STRING"
```

Use this command. It will create a dump in your current working DIR.

Answer (score 1):

MS has finally introduced a **backup policy feature** to CosmosDB!
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore#modify-the-backup-interval-and-retention-period

I guess this removes the need for third party and/or custom tools to do such a basic Ops routine.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic backup is not for free... Standard support plan ($100/mo)

I'm using free [A̶z̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶C̶o̶s̶m̶o̶s̶ ̶D̶B̶ ̶D̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶M̶i̶g̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶T̶o̶o̶l̶](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

EDIT: thx @e2eDev link [Azure Cosmos DB Data Migration Tool 1.8.3 on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/releases/tag/1.8.3)

There is both GUI tool `dtui.exe` even CLI tool `dt.exe`

Supports many protocols and even JSON format (for both import and export).

Comment: above link is not working. instead try this https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-datamigrationtool/releases/tag/1.8.3 this is archived version