# How to backup and restore azure cosmos grpah db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases

I have an azure cosmos graph db and i want to have an strategy of backup and restore in case that I have to do a rollback.

By now I have only found this oficial [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/online-backup-and-restore) which says "If the data is accidentally dropped or corrupted, contact Azure support within eight hours."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I backup an Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714960/how-can-i-backup-an-azure-cosmos-db)

Comment: Hi, i think there are differences between the documents databases and graph databases. I'm not sure, this is why I'm asking

Comment: Did you try using the tool to backup your data?