# How to see Azure CosmosDB backup?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Azure Cosmos DB takes snapshots of your data every four hours. At any given time, only the last two snapshots are retained. However, if the container or database is deleted, Azure Cosmos DB retains the existing snapshots of a given container or database for 30 days.

How can I see those snapshots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to see them.

CosmosDB uses Azure Blob storage in the same region as your database's write region for backups. If you have multiple write regions, CosmosDB picks one of them to store your backups. But wait, Microsoft does not stop there! Each snapshot of the backups in Azure Blob storage gets replicated again to another region for disaster recovery.

All these operations do not cost you any extra charge or RU. Also backups do not affect the performance of your databases. If you need to [restore data for any reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50714960/how-can-i-backup-an-azure-cosmos-db), you need to contact **Azure support within 8 hours**!

Comment: contacting azure support wont help. you need to delete the db, else the backup will get overwritten